# How do I add a class to outer div if the file name span is populated

Tags: jquery, css

How can I add a class to the 'span class="btn"' so that the color of this changes when a file has successfully been uploaded by the user. So far I have the following code;

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span>Browse</span>
  <input type="file" class="file1" />
  </span>
  <span class="fileinput-filename1"></span><span class="fileinput-new">No file chosen</span>
</div>
```

Then my script to update the file name span is as follows

```
            $(".file1").on('change', function() {
                var fileName = $(this).val();
                $(".fileinput-filename1").html(fileName);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

When the file name is updated you can use jQuery to add a new class to the button

```
$('.btn').addClass('success');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use btn class for a span, but also there is text or label to reach this. `<span id="upload" class="label label-success">`

So you can `<span id="upload" class="label">`
and simply add label-success with jquery if the load is OK. (you must use Ajax to get the server OK or KO response and, if OK change it to label-success, else change it to  label-danger.

```
//check if upload is ok
$('#upload').addClass('label-success');
$('#upload').empty(); 
$('#upload').text('Success');
//else
$('#upload').addClass('label-danger');
$('#upload').empty(); 
$('#upload').text('Failed');
```

is this what you want?

Comment: I will also need the text 'Browse' to change to 'Success' as well on the button.

Comment: $('#upload').empty();
$('#upload').text('Success');

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the file will not be uploaded until the form is submitted, and so other answers will not work. One possible solution would be to upload the file via ajax when the user browses to a file, and then change the span class when that is successful.

```
$(".file1").on('change', function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    $(".fileinput-filename1").html(fileName);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<form url goes here>",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: {
            file: filename
        },
        success: function () {
            $('.fileinput-filename1').addClass('label-success');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First give id to your span to remove another issues and after that On success of file upload just add class which has the property to change the color, in your span by jquery code

$('#div-to-add-class').addClaas('your-class-name');